# Using two iterators in _.uniq()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I understand that given an array of objects, I can use [`_.uniq()`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-50) to filter out the unique objects by checking against an object property common to each object. I’m wondering, can I check against two properties at once?

For example:

```
var foo = [
    {"name":"Steve", "age":"56", "car":"Porsche"}, 
    {"name":"Steve", "age":"56", "car":"Mercedes"}, 
    {"name":"Bill", "age":"57", "car":"Porsche"},
    {"name":"Linus", "age":"56", "car":"Mercedes"}
];

var bar = _.unique(foo, false, function(obj, k, v){
    return obj.name && obj.age;
});

console.log(bar);
```

I was quite hoping I’d get back Steve, Bill and Linus. However, [it looks as though only `obj.age` is being checked against](http://jsfiddle.net/Ppgxc/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
return obj.name && obj.age;
```

means:

```
if (!obj.name)
  return obj.name;
return obj.age;
```

Only one value is returned. In your case, since all the names are non-empty, the age will be returned.

If you want to find items that are unique based on the *combination* of name and age, you could do this:

```
return obj.name + "---" + obj.age; // replace "---" with whatever
```

That returns a string that's built from both the name and the age.

Comment: That’s what I thought. Is it possible to do what I’m trying to do?

Comment: This seems like black magic to me. It seems it doesn’t matter what I put in between the properties, as long as it’s a string. It seems even `obj.name + obj.age` works.

Comment: Well all that `_.uniq()` does is make sure that there's only one of each value returned. If `_.uniq` also allowed you to pass in a *comparator* function, you could make things a lot fancier. However, Underscore is pretty spartan in its API setup.

Answer (score 2):

The iterator function is meant to be a comparison basis. Perhaps not the best answer out there, but instead of

```
return obj.name && obj.age;
```

Try

```
return obj.name + '|' + obj.age;
```